# Exception between C# and Outlook

Tags: c#, exception, outlook

I have a simple code to open a compose email in Outlook 2013 using C#. It works without any issues when Outlook is not running, but when Outlook is already open I get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

Here is my simple code:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
        mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
        mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";
        mailItem.Display(true);
```

I also get these from Visual Studio output windows complaining about symbols which I have no idea about!:

```
Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
'mCPanel.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: mCPanel.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'mCPanel.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: mCPanel.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\office.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

Any help is appreciated?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by a difference in security contexts. Is either Outlook or your app running with elevated privileges?

Comment: I didn't make any changes. How can I check this?

Comment: Are you running either app as an Administrator? Look at the Compatibility tab if using a shortcut.

Comment: I am actually using visual studio and am debugging my code. so no I am not using any shortcut. any other idea?

Comment: Is VS itself running with elevated privileges? Did you disable the VS hosting process in the project options?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything! How can I check this?

Comment: How do you start VS? Is it a shortcut? Did you check its compatibility tab? Ti disable the VS hosting process, go to the project options, Debug tab, uncheck the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox.